# Can you pass Javascript Variable from one function to another using HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to pass Javascript from one function to the next through my an onclick() function on my webpage:

Within the first funciton I am writing a table and one part of which creates this cell.

`table += "<td><a onclick=assetDetails(assetId) href='#'>"+title+"</a></td>";`

This is taking the variable `title` and passing it to my HTML page as a hyperlink to execute the assetDetails funciton on click.

`function assetDetails(assetId){
console.log(assetId);
}`

My assetDetails function is formatted like the above.

When I click the hyperlink it tells me that the assetId variable is unidentified.

I have tried this:

`table += "<td><a onclick=assetDetails("+assetId+") href='#'>"+title+"</a></td>";`

This passes the value of my variable and tells me that it is unidentified as well.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you know the difference between a local variable and a global?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably wrap the `assetId` variable with quotes like this:

```
table += "<td><a onclick=assetDetails('"+assetId+"') href='#'>"+title+"</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define assestId as an attribute for the  tag and in your JS access the value by getAttribute DOM function.

Answer (score 0):

```
table += "<td><a onclick=assetDetails(assetId) href='#'>"+title+"</a></td>";
```

When this is in html assestId will not exists in the scope unless its a global variable in which case why pass it. Perhaps you was trying to do this.

```
table += "<td><a onclick=assetDetails('" + assetId + "') href='#'>"+title+"</a></td>";
```

I think you are also missing some quotes.

I would recommend creating your table td using document.createElement("td"). This way you can then assign a onlick to it using addEventListener.

Answer (score 0):

You missed quotes inside the onclick function, try:

```
table += "<td><a onclick=assetDetails('"+assetId+"') href='#'>"+title+"</a></td>";
```

This should work because when you create the table string, 'assesId' is known and inserted into the string like:

```
var assetId = 'test';
var title = 'title';
var tsTest = "<td><a onclick=\"assetDetails('"+assetId+"')\" href='#'>"+title+"</a></td>";
```

becomes:

```
<td><a onclick="assetDetails('test')" href='#'>title</a></td>
```

**But**: this is the old way of doing this.
You could better use the dom api (document.createElement, etc.) or use a library like jQuery:

```
var link = jQuery("<a href='#'>title</a>");
link.click(function() {
    // assetId is still known when clicked because of js closure
    console.log(assetId);
})
```